# Python: Calculate the max height of a tree with multiple children

Tags: python, tree

```
def __init__(self,label=None):
    self.label = label
    self.leftMostChild = None
    self.RightSibling = None


def height(self):
    if self.leftMostChild == None and self.RightSibling == None:
        return 0
    else:
        if self.leftMostChild:
            return self.leftMostChild.height() + 1

        if self.RightSibling:
            return self.RightSibling.height()
```

Apparently, the height is off by 1. When a tree with height 3 is produced, 2 gets return after calling the function height. I am not sure where did i do wrong in this function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When a node has children, you immediately stop considering any siblings to its right. (Also, you should really try to be consistent with your capitalization.)

Comment: The names `leftMostChild` and `RightSibling` are a little confusing, but shouldn't you be evaluating the height of both subtrees then using the larger to determine the height of the current tree?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: It looks to me like this is probably intended to be a variable-degree tree based on linked lists of siblings, so the parent of `self.RightSibling` is `self`'s parent, not `self`. It's basically encoding a variable-degree tree in a binary tree. That's why the names are that way, and why we're not adding 1 to `self.RightSibling.height()`. (We do still need to look at both subtrees, as you say.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return causes a function to end immediately. This means that if a node has both a left most child and a right sibling, the right sibling will never be evaluated.  Here is the function with only one return for each if/else branch.

```
def height(self):
    if self.leftMostChild == None and self.RightSibling == None:
        return 0
    else:
        leftHeight = rightHeight = 0
        if self.leftMostChild:
            leftHeight =  self.leftMostChild.height() + 1

        if self.RightSibling:
            rightHeight = self.RightSibling.height()
        return max(leftHeight, rightHeight)
```

This can be further simplified to:

```
def height(self):
    leftHeight = rightHeight = 0
    if self.leftMostChild:
        leftHeight =  self.leftMostChild.height() + 1
    if self.RightSibling:
        rightHeight = self.RightSibling.height()
    return max(leftHeight, rightHeight)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, that fixed it my issue.